# I need to start a bot on a server with nohup

Tags: python, telethon

I need to start a bot on a server. I use nohup, but it's wrong. Telethon uses input() for authorization. But nonup ignores this function. What do I have to do?

Code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id   = 0
api_hash = 'hash'

session = 'my'

client = TelegramClient('my', api_id, api_hash)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
async def func(event):

    name_bot = '@betta_test'

    chat = await client.get_entity(name_bot)

    await event.message.forward_to(chat)


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: First start your script without nohup to generate a session then use nohup to run it. you could also provide your own callbacks to the start function

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
nohup python3 /path/to/your/file.py >> log.txt &
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include any piece of reference, advice and guidelines here. Code-only answers give a solution but not really an answer.